# How to sychronously call or wait for an asynchronous callback to complete?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, callback, synchronization

Here's a demo of code that is calling an "old library" which if successful, returns nothing, and if error, throws an exception.

```
public void ExampleCallOldCode()
{
    List<string> users = new List<string>() {"user123", "user456"};
    foreach (string userId in users)
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Processing {userId} started");
            DoSomethingSynchronously(userId);
            Console.WriteLine($"Processing {userId} completed");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Processing {userId} FAILED. {e.Message}");
        }
    }
}

public void DoSomethingSynchronously(string userId)
{
    if (userId.Contains("123"))
        Console.WriteLine($"Doing something with {userId}");
    else
        throw new Exception("UserId needs to contain 123.");
}
```

We are now upgrading/integrating to a "new library" which performs the work asynchronously (which uses batching/queuing logic behind the scenese) and uses callbacks to notify of success or failure.

FYI: The "old library" is a wrapper that send emails. The new library is [Segment's Analytics.Net package](https://github.com/segmentio/Analytics.NET)

I don't want to change too much of the old code (it is used in MANY places).

- How do I wait synchronously for the new library to complete and invoke the callback function?

  - e.g. Should I use `AutoResetEvents` and call `WaitOne`?
  - Or are there better options?
- How do I handle errors?
- Would I create a wrapper and throw an exception in the failure callback function?

```
public void ExampleNewCode()
{
    // Segment initialization and payload setup
    string writeKey = "PqRStUv1WxYzraGHijkA1Pz0AbcDE12F"; 
    Config configWithBatchingOff = new Config().SetAsync(false);
    Segment.Analytics.Initialize(writeKey, configWithBatchingOff);

    Context context = new Context() {{"appName", "MyApp"}};
    Options optionsContext = new Options().SetContext(context);
    Properties properties = new Properties() {{"my_first_prop", "foo bar"}};

    // setup callback handlers
    Analytics.Client.Failed += FailureHandler;
    Analytics.Client.Succeeded += SuccessHandler;
    Logger.Handlers += LogHandler;

    // **** 
    // the old code structure I want to preserve. HOW DO I MAKE THIS WORK ???
    // **** 
    List<string> users = new List<string>() { "user123", "user456" };
    foreach (string userId in users)
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Processing {userId} started");
            Analytics.Client.Track(userId, "Test Fired", properties, optionsContext);
            Console.WriteLine($"Processing {userId} completed");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Processing {userId} FAILED. {e.Message}");
        }
    }
}

public void FailureHandler(BaseAction action, System.Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"FailureHandler called for userid={action.UserId}"); 
}
public void SuccessHandler(BaseAction action)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"SuccessHandler called for userid={action.UserId}");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly then you can solve this problem by using `TaskCompletionSource`.

For the sake of simplicity I've created a dummy class which might raise an `OnSuccess` or an `OnFailure` event depending on the provided parameter:

```
public class Dummy
{
    public event EventHandler OnFailure;
    public event EventHandler OnSuccess;

    public void DoWork(int i)
    {
        if (i % 2 == 0) OnFailure?.Invoke(this, null);
        else OnSuccess?.Invoke(this, null);
    }
}
```

On the consumer side you can do the following:

```
private static TaskCompletionSource<object> signalling = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Calling new code");
    var dummy = new Dummy();
    dummy.OnSuccess += Dummy_OnSuccess;
    dummy.OnFailure += Dummy_OnFailure;

    dummy.DoWork(2);
    try
    {
        await signalling.Task;
        Console.WriteLine("New code has finished");
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("New code has failed");
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Calling old code");          
}

private static void Dummy_OnFailure(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    signalling.TrySetException(new Exception("Operation failed"));
}

private static void Dummy_OnSuccess(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    signalling.TrySetResult(null);
}
```

- Whenever the `OnFailure` event is emitted then call the `TrySetException` on the `TaskCompletionSource` to indicate that the operation has been finished without luck
- Whenever the `OnSuccess` event is emitted the we call the `TrySetResult` on the `TaskCompletionSource` to indicate that the operation has been finished with luck
- We are `await`-ing the `TaskCompletionSource` that's why we can be sure that either the requested operation succeeded or failed after the line of `await`

Comment: Thanks, let me give this a try and respond back later. I definitely appreciate the sample code.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding using the segment library, the way you get to know if an action (Identify, Group, Track, Alias, Page or Screen) succeeds or fails when being sent to Segment Server is setting up callback handlers like you did (Failed, Succeeded) and also the Logger Handler.

As your example above, both Succeeded and Failed callbacks receive by parameter the BaseAction which allows you to have information regarding the Action that succeeded or failed.

As you have mentioned, Analytics.NET library sends it Actions asynchronously enqueuing them and when the queue is full then it proceeds to flush those actions and send them in a batch to the segment server. So if you want to send automatically to Segment's server once you invoke any of the Actions, you should call Analytics.Client.Flush() so as to get inmediate feedback on the Succeeded or Failed Callback and the Loggers handler. In your code it will be:

```
public void ExampleNewCode()
{
    // Segment initialization and payload setup
    string writeKey = "PqRStUv1WxYzraGHijkA1Pz0AbcDE12F"; 
    Config configWithBatchingOff = new Config().SetAsync(false);
    Segment.Analytics.Initialize(writeKey, configWithBatchingOff);

    Context context = new Context() {{"appName", "MyApp"}};
    Options optionsContext = new Options().SetContext(context);
    Properties properties = new Properties() {{"my_first_prop", "foo bar"}};

    // setup callback handlers
    Analytics.Client.Failed += FailureHandler;
    Analytics.Client.Succeeded += SuccessHandler;
    Logger.Handlers += LogHandler;

    List<string> users = new List<string>() { "user123", "user456" };
    foreach (string userId in users)
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Processing {userId} started");
            Analytics.Client.Track(userId, "Test Fired", properties, optionsContext);
            Analytics.Client.Flush();
            Console.WriteLine($"Processing {userId} completed");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Processing {userId} FAILED. {e.Message}");
        }
    }
}

public void FailureHandler(BaseAction action, System.Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"FailureHandler called for userid={action.UserId}"); 
}
public void SuccessHandler(BaseAction action)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"SuccessHandler called for userid={action.UserId}");
}
```